# Doctrine2 named queries

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I can't find any documentation about named queries in Doctrine2. 
Please help.
Does Doctrine2 have a named queries feature?

Comment: You mean http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#named-native-query

Comment: Yes, I saw it early, but I think that NamedNativeQuery and NamedQuery are not the same. What do you think?

Comment: You've done a good answer for your original Question here, but it's not an SO Answer - might be useful to make it an Answer and accept it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use

1. NamedQuery - DQL. Example

   ```
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\NamedQuery;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\NamedQueries;

   /**
   * @Entity
   * @Table(name="cms_users")
   * @NamedQueries({
   *     @NamedQuery(name="activated", query="SELECT u FROM __CLASS__ u WHERE u.status = 1")
   * })
   */
   class CmsUser
   {}
   ```

   And call it like

   ```
   $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:CmsUser')
       ->createNamedQuery('activated')
       ->getResult();
   ```
2. NamedNativeQuery - SQL. More information here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#named-native-query
3. Collecting a queries in your EntityRepository, like:

   ```
   namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Repository;

   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

   class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
   {
       public function findAllOrderedByName()
       {
           return $this->getEntityManager()
               ->createQuery('SELECT p FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p ORDER BY p.name ASC')
               ->getResult();
       }
   }
   ```

   More information here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Similar topic here:
[https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/doctrine-user/K-D5ta5tZ3Y[1-25]](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/doctrine-user/K-D5ta5tZ3Y%5b1-25%5d)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you'll be interested by the EntityRepositories where you can create and store complex Doctrine queries, and call theme in your project where you want:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Comment: Thanks, but no. 
I found only that https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/tests/Doctrine/Tests/Models/CMS/CmsUser.php
if anyone know where I can read about Named Queries in Doctrine2, please let me know.
P.S: named queries in Doctrine 1.2 here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#named-queries

Comment: But IMO, it's strictly the same! Doctrine in standalone allow you to create complex queries and store them by name for later. Symfony2 adopts this same principle with its EntityRepository, with the same purpose: any query more complex than a simple findBy is written and stored in a Repository, to be called simplen anywhere.

Comment: Maybe, maybe =) But in the Doctrine 1.2.4 I can create a several small named queries instead of defining a methods in Doctrine_Table class. And I think Doctrine_Table in the Doctrine 1.2.4 and Repository in the Doctrine 2 are the same, but in Doctrine 1.2.4 I still can create a named queries, and I like it. OK, I accept your answer as Accepted. P.S.: as I know EntityRepository is a part of Doctrine and not symfony

Comment: Ok, nice you've find 1) for named query. I'll try it, I've learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the functions used internally by annotation notation in the constructor of your repository if you don't want to mess up your entity definition:

```
namespace MyBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CmsUserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function __construct($em, \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)
    {
        $this->getClassMetadata()->addNamedQuery(array(
            'name'  => 'activated',
            'query' => 'SELECT u FROM __CLASS__ u WHERE u.status = 1'
        ));
    }
}
```

You can also replace the `__CLASS__` part of the statement with the namespace and class of your entity like `MyBundle\Entity\CmsUser`

Answer (score 0):

I found this question looking for Native Named Query examples, the above answer helped me so I figured I'd share how to do a native named query in the same way.

Add this to the constructor for your entity repository

```
public function __construct($em, \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)
{
    parent::__construct($em, $class);
    $this->getClassMetadata()->addNamedNativeQuery(
        array('name' => 'published', 
              'query' => 'SELECT 
                  t0.id AS id, 
                  t0.tracking_uri AS tracking_uri, 
                  t0.name AS name, 
                  t0.description AS description, 
                  t0.url_name AS url_name,
                  t0.status_type_id as status_type_id
                FROM 
                  store.store t0 
                WHERE 
                  t0.status_type_id = 2', 
               'resultClass' => '__CLASS__',
               'resultSetMapping' => array('entities' => array('entityClass' => '__CLASS__',
                                                               'fields'      => array('id'           => 'id',
                                                                                      'tracking_url' => 'tracking_url',
                                                                                      'name'         => 'name',
                                                                                      'description'  => 'description',
                                                                                      'url_name'     => 'url_name',
                                                                                      'status_type'  => 'status_type_id')))));
}
```

Here's a clip of my test for this

```
public function testNamedNativeQueryPublished()
{
    $results = $this->em->getRepository('MyBundle:Store')->createNativeNamedQuery('published')->execute();

    foreach ($results as $store)
    {
        $this->assertEquals(2, $store->getStatusType());
    }
}
```