# Is it possible to use result of an SQL function as a field in Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Assume I have `Product` entities and `Review` entities attached to products. Is it possible to attach a fields to a `Product` entity based on some result returned by an SQL query? Like attaching a `ReviewsCount` field equal to `COUNT(Reviews.ID) as ReviewsCount`.

I know it is possible to do that in a function like

```
public function getReviewsCount() {
    return count($this->Reviews);
}
```

But I want doing this with SQL to minimize number of database queries and increase performance, as normally I may not need to load hundreds of reviews, but still need to know there number. I think running SQL's `COUNT` would be much faster than going through 100 Products and calculating 100 Reviews for each. Moreover, that is just example, on practice I need more complex functions, that I think MySQL would process faster. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't think so. Have you considered using named queries [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016378/doctrine2-named-queries) ?

Comment: Yes. The I noticed the problem of Native Queries in my comment to Tomasz Madeyski's answer. The problem is that they return scalars together with entities, while I want them to be entities' fields to avoid mess.

Answer (score 8):

You can map a [single column result to an entity field](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#scalar-results) - look at [native queries](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) and **ResultSetMapping** to achieve this.  As a simple example:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

$sql = '
    SELECT p.*, COUNT(r.id)
    FROM products p
    LEFT JOIN reviews r ON p.id = r.product_id
';

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('AppBundle\Entity\Product', 'p');
$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'COUNT(id)', 'reviewsCount');

$query   = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$results = $query->getResult();
```

Then in your Product entity you would have a `$reviewsCount` field and the count would be mapped to that.  Note that this will only work if you have a column defined in the Doctrine metadata, like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $reviewsCount;

public function getReviewsCount()
{
    return $this->reviewsCount;
}
```

This is what is suggested by the [Aggregate Fields](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html) Doctrine documentation.  The problem is here is that you are essentially making Doctrine think you have another column in your database called `reviews_count`, which is what you don't want.  So, this will still work without physically adding that column, but if you ever run a `doctrine:schema:update` it's going to add that column in for you.  Unfortunately Doctrine does not really allow virtual properties, so another solution would be to write your own custom hydrator, or perhaps subscribe to the `loadClassMetadata` event and manually add the mapping yourself after your particular entity (or entities) load.

Note that if you do something like `COUNT(r.id) AS reviewsCount` then you can no longer use `COUNT(id)` in your `addFieldResult()` function, and must instead use the alias `reviewsCount` for that second parameter.

You can also use the [`ResultSetMappingBuilder`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder) as a start into using the result set mapping.

My actual suggestion is to do this manually instead of going through all of that extra stuff.  Essentially create a normal query that returns both your entity and scalar results into an array, then set the scalar result to a corresponding, unmapped field on your entity, and return the entity.

Comment: That could be an ideal solution, but I get an "Undefined index: ReviewsCount" exception if I assign result to a property, not linked to a column. Even if that property exists and is public. Is there a way to make a property accessible by Doctrine without assigning it to a database column?

Comment: The case has to match, so it would have to be $reviewsCount instead of $ReviewsCount

Comment: I understand it. It matches. Nevertheless it works only if I assign a database Column to that field (even if I don't do doctrine:schema:update). But even in that case, if I get the same entities with a different query - it will overwrite changes reseting this field, although I keep these results separately. It looks like doctrine caches results and returns me the same entities, but with fields reloaded and reviewsCount field reset.

Comment: Could you kind of post what you have?  Because it should be working with your COUNT() column and not just a physical database column.

Comment: I've just done all according to what you have written. Blog application: Posts instead of Products and Comments instead of Reviews. Result id the same: "Notice: Undefined index: CommentsCount".

Comment: Can you post your query?  Undefined index would mean it's not in the resulting array and not have anything to do with the entity

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT Posts.*, COUNT(Comments.ID) as CommentsCount FROM Posts LEFT JOIN Comments ON Posts.ID = Comments.Post';
    $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('BlogBundle\Entity\Post', 'p');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'CommentsCount', 'CommentsCount');
    $query   =  $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    $results = $query->getResult();

Comment: Query: 

SELECT 
  Posts.*, 
  COUNT(Comments.ID) as CommentsCount 
FROM 
  Posts 
  LEFT JOIN Comments ON Posts.ID = Comments.Post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103616/discussion-between-jason-roman-and-multis).

Comment: if I change $rsm like that: $rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'CommentsCount', 'CommentsCountX'); it says "Undefined index CommentsCountX", not "Undefined index Comments", so I think it's about rsm, not CommentsCount field in database response.

Answer (score 3):

After detailed investigation I've found there are several ways to do something close to what I wanted including listed in other answers, but all of them have some minuses. Finally I've decided to use [CustomHydrators](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes). It seems that properties not managed with ORM cannot be mapped with ResultSetMapping as fields, but can be got as scalars and attached to an entity manually (as PHP allows to attach object properties on the fly). However, result that you get from doctrine remains in the cache. That means properties set in that way may be reset if you make some other query that would contain these entities too.

Another way to do that was adding these field directly to doctrine's metadata cache. I tried doing that in a CustomHydrator:

```
protected function getClassMetadata($className)
{
    if ( ! isset($this->_metadataCache[$className])) {
        $this->_metadataCache[$className] = $this->_em->getClassMetadata($className);

        if ($className === "SomeBundle\Entity\Product") {
            $this->insertField($className, "ReviewsCount");
        }
    }

    return $this->_metadataCache[$className];
}

protected function insertField($className, $fieldName) {
    $this->_metadataCache[$className]->fieldMappings[$fieldName] = ["fieldName" => $fieldName, "type" => "text", "scale" => 0, "length" => null, "unique" => false, "nullable" => true, "precision" => 0];
    $this->_metadataCache[$className]->reflFields[$fieldName] = new \ReflectionProperty($className, $fieldName);

    return $this->_metadataCache[$className];
}
```

However, that method also had problems with entities' properties reset. So, my final solution was just to use stdClass to get the same structure, but not managed by doctrine:

```
namespace SomeBundle;

use PDO;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

class CustomHydrator extends \Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator {
    public function hydrateAll($stmt, $resultSetMapping, array $hints = array()) {
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $result = [];

        foreach($resultSetMapping->entityMappings as $root => $something) {
            $rootIDField = $this->getIDFieldName($root, $resultSetMapping);

            foreach($data as $row) {
                $key = $this->findEntityByID($result, $row[$rootIDField]);

                if ($key === null) {
                    $result[] = new \stdClass();
                    end($result);
                    $key = key($result);
                }

                foreach ($row as $column => $field)
                    if (isset($resultSetMapping->columnOwnerMap[$column]))
                        $this->attach($result[$key], $field, $this->getPath($root, $resultSetMapping, $column));
            }
        }


        return $result;
    }

    private function getIDFieldName($entityAlias, ResultSetMapping $rsm) {
        foreach ($rsm->fieldMappings as $key => $field)
            if ($field === 'ID' && $rsm->columnOwnerMap[$key] === $entityAlias) return $key;

            return null;
    }

    private function findEntityByID($array, $ID) {
        foreach($array as $index => $entity)
            if (isset($entity->ID) && $entity->ID === $ID) return $index;

        return null;
    }

    private function getPath($root, ResultSetMapping $rsm, $column) {
        $path = [$rsm->fieldMappings[$column]];
        if ($rsm->columnOwnerMap[$column] !== $root) 
            array_splice($path, 0, 0, $this->getParent($root, $rsm, $rsm->columnOwnerMap[$column]));

        return $path;
    }

    private function getParent($root, ResultSetMapping $rsm, $entityAlias) {
        $path = [];
        if (isset($rsm->parentAliasMap[$entityAlias])) {
            $path[] = $rsm->relationMap[$entityAlias];
            array_splice($path, 0, 0, $this->getParent($root, $rsm, array_search($rsm->parentAliasMap[$entityAlias], $rsm->relationMap)));
        }

        return $path;
    }

    private function attach($object, $field, $place) {
        if (count($place) > 1) {
            $prop = $place[0];
            array_splice($place, 0, 1);
            if (!isset($object->{$prop})) $object->{$prop} = new \stdClass();
            $this->attach($object->{$prop}, $field, $place);
        } else {
            $prop = $place[0];
            $object->{$prop} = $field;
        }
    }
}
```

With that class you can get any structure and attach any entities however you like:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT p.*, COUNT(r.id)
    FROM products p
    LEFT JOIN reviews r ON p.id = r.product_id
';

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('SomeBundle\Entity\Product', 'p');
$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'COUNT(id)', 'reviewsCount');

$query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

$em->getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode('CustomHydrator', 'SomeBundle\CustomHydrator');
$results = $query->getResult('CustomHydrator');
```

Hope that may help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, you need to use `QueryBuilder` to achieve that:

```
$result = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p, count(r.id) as countResult')
    ->leftJoin('p.Review', 'r')
    ->groupBy('r.id')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult();
```

and now you can do something like:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['countResult'];
    echo $row['anyOtherProductField'];
}
```

Comment: The problem is that in that case I get a scalar, separate from an entity. That may not be a problem if all these scalars are attached to the same entity, but what if they should be attached to different entities? Like I want to select Products and Reviews, and for Products I want to have the number of Reviews, while for Reviews I want to have number of likes and dislikes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Doctrine 2.1+, consider using [EXTRA_LAZY associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html):

They allow you to implement a method like yours in your entity, doing a straight count on the association instead of retrieving all the entities in it:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="Product" fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
*/
private $Reviews;

public function getReviewsCount() {
    return $this->Reviews->count();
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but still not what I need. As I mentioned, on practice calculations are a bit more complex. Like I need to know the number of positive Reviews and negative Reviews, which seems to be impossible without loading all the collection and going through it.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers didn't help me, but I found a solution doing the following:

My use case was different so the code is a mock. But the key is to use `addScalarResult` and then cleanup the result while setting the aggregate on the entity.

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder;

// ...

$sql = "
  SELECT p.*, COUNT(r.id) AS reviewCount
  FROM products p 
  LEFT JOIN reviews r ON p.id = r.product_id
";

$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($em, ResultSetMappingBuilder::COLUMN_RENAMING_CUSTOM);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('App\Entity\Product', 'p');
$rsm->addScalarResult('reviewCount', 'reviewCount');

$query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$result = $query->getResult();

// APPEND the aggregated field to the Entities
$aggregatedResult = [];
foreach ($result as $resultItem) {
  $product = $resultItem[0];
  $product->setReviewCount( $resultItem["reviewCount"] );
  array_push($aggregatedResult, $product);
}

return $aggregatedResult;
```