# Doctrine findAll() does not find column when using addMetaResult

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Doctrine and ResultSetMappingBuilder with `addMetaResult()`.
I got native query in my repository with mapping to entity and it works nicely, the code structure is like this:

```
 $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($entityManager);
 $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('AppBundle\Entity\Example', 'e');
 $rsm->addFieldResult('e', 'id', 'id');
 $rsm->addMetaResult('e', 'value', 'value');

 $sql = "SELECT id, 5 as value FROM table";
 $query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)
 $result = $query->getResult();
```

My entity.yml looks like that:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Example:  
  ...
  fields:
     id:
        type: smallint
        nullable: false
        options:
            unsigned: true
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
     value:
       type: integer
```

But when I use that entity somewhere else with standard entity manager methods like this:

```
$this->exampleRepo->find(5);
```

Then I get the error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.value' in 'field list'

it is because I do not have real column 'value' in my table, it is meta column. Do there is any config to skip that column if it is not in Native Query or to skip if it does not exists or I have to override method `find()` in repository and add mapping in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35409130/1307183), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35414165/1307183) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35437708/1307183) to that question for more context.

The short answer is that you're running into a limitation with Doctrine in that you cannot have virtual properties that appear to be database columns but aren't.  So when you add this to your **entity.yml:**

```
value:
    type: integer
```

What you're telling Doctrine is that there is a **value** column on your **Example** entity.  So any Doctrine query you're attempting to run *except* is going to break.  The reason why your original query does not is because you are running a native query and explicitly performing the mapping yourself.

So you probably felt like you found a way to workaround Doctrine's limitation, but you did not.

The simplest solution would be to maintain a non-mapped **value** field inside your Example entity, then when you need to query that, simply add it to your Doctrine query and then manually set what you need.  Something like this:

```
$entityResults = [];

/**
 * return array of arrays like: [
 *     ['example' => Example entity, 'value' => int value],
 *     ['example' => Example entity, 'value' => int value],
 * ]
 */
$results = $em
    ->createQuery('SELECT e AS example, 5 AS value FROM AppBundle:Example')
    ->getResult();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $result['example']->setValue($result['value]);
    $entityResults[] = $result['example'];
}

return $entityResults;
```

If you want something a little more global you could look at adding a [custom hydrator](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes) instead.

Comment: Ya, I did, something like that, but only not in repo, but in entity, I do my calculations inside getValue method instead of sql, and I do not select value at all in query. Real query was very big and complex so I did not wanted to rewrite it in PHP thats why I asked this question. But your answer is good for other people, so I will mark it correct :)

Comment: Sounds good. Your method, being doable for your situation, is likely the fastest implementation.